# How to prevent calloc failure crashing my program?

Tags: c++, memory, crash

How can I prevent the following code crashing my program?

```
::MessageBox(NULL, L"before", NULL, MB_OK);
void* x = ::calloc(1, -1);
::MessageBox(NULL, L"after", NULL, MB_OK);
```

When I run this code I get the "before" message box, then the program crashes with an "unhandled win32 exception" (the "after" message box never appears).

I know the args to calloc are making it crash by asking for way too much memory! What I want to know is how to prevent the crash so that I get control back and can handle the lack of memory some other way?

(Windows XP, Visual Studio 2005)

Comment: I am purposely passing an impossible size to calloc to force it to fail. I am trying to handle the case when my program will fail due to lack of memory on the system. This merely simulates that situation!!!

Comment: In the same spirit that good bug reports include the "expected behavior", you should say that you expect `calloc()` to return `NULL` and not to crash your program. That would save you the comments from users who have read too quickly.

Comment: Looks like a bug, anyway: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356599/calloc-crashes-if-total-size-heap-maxreq

Comment: By the way, `::calloc(1, -1)` is not C. If there is no other way your program in some language that I don't know anything about is doing something reprehensible, you have found a bug and you should report it to the provider of your compiler, not here.

Comment: It looks like he's just compiling C with a C++ compiler (which would make `::calloc` valid).

Comment: Check your compiler/linker/library options.  You may be able to change the error-handling mechanism and persuade calloc() to return a void pointer instead of raising an exception that you cannot catch.

Comment: @James: since the code isn't C, in fact he's compiling C++ with a C++ compiler ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, but if he tagged this question C++ he'd already have been told to use some std::magic::boost::smart_memory_super_auto_allocator instead.

Comment: Erm, yes it's C++ really! Oops. I changed the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Microsoft calloc (it's supposed to return null, not crash):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356599/calloc-crashes-if-total-size-heap-maxreq

So you need to use a newer version of their C runtime.

Comment: This is the right answer. Follow the link to see why (it's a bug in calloc that Microsoft have subsequently fixed). The workaround is to use malloc and do the memset yourself!

Answer (score 0):

If you use malloc you can just if(x==NULL){return GetLastError();}

It is not a real answer because I sugested another function but it should work. Also check SetErrorMode

Comment: I tried SetErrorMode. It gets rid of the Windows "unhandled win32 exception" message box, but the program still crashes. :( ie: You get the "before" message box but the "after" message box never appears. Using malloc works though! Thanks.

Comment: Do not forget to free your buffer then